# web3.js how to call receive() external payable?

Tags: web3js, contract-development, javascript, ganache

firstly, I have a code in a contract as below:

```
    receive() external payable {
        // function enter() external payable {
        require(msg.value > 0.1 ether, "require minimum 0.1 ether! ");
        players.push(payable(msg.sender));
    }
```

then I test it in the ganache with mocha and web3.js, the js code as below:

```
        await mycontract.send({
            from: accounts[1],
            value: web3.utils.toWei('2', 'ether')
        });
```

but got the error   `TypeError: mycontract.send is not a function`

then I update the contract as `function enter() external payable` , so js works as below:

```
        await mycontract.methods.enter().send({
            from: accounts[2],
            value: web3.utils.toWei('2', 'ether')
        });
```

But I'm wondering is there a solution as I wrote as the first type?

Answer (score 1):

The `receive()` function does not exist but the fallback function exists, it will be triggered when a contract is sent Ether without any data. To interact with this `receive()` function in `web3.js`, you don't call it directly, you simply send Ether to the contract address.

In the code below just replace `contract.address` with the address of your deployed contract

```
web3.eth.sendTransaction({
    from: accounts[1],
    to: contract.address,
    value: web3.utils.toWei('2', 'ether')
});
```